# Is it possible to tell whether the user is visiting my page inside Facebook app?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I noticed that in the native iPhone Facebook app, people can directly open links without switching to Safari or another browser. Is it possible for a webpage to tell whether the user is in that app-wrapped browser?

Comment: This is unclear. In your first sentence "in facebook people can directly open links without switching to safari." Why would someone switch browsers? Are you using a facebook app on a mobile device? And if so which one? And what do you mean by "app-wrapped browser"?

Comment: I think the most clever way to do this is to set a subdomain specifically for this purpose.

Comment: You should take a look at window.navigator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

It returns information about the browser used to display the site. I have no way to test it (as I have no access to iOS devices), but there _should_ be some indication if the visitor uses facebook.

Also, please keep in mind that lot of values returned with this function are unreliable, as it's easy to fake them.

Comment: @benedekadam thanks. actually I am looking for someone happen to work with Facebook web app development that might be aware of this.

Comment: So, are you asking whether you, as a Facebook app developer, can tell whether each user is using a mobile app or is using Facebook in a regular browser?

Comment: @cutmancometh No. I am not a Facebook app developer. I just want to know whether the user are visiting my webpage (a very ordinary web page) inside a Facebook Mobile App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand now. You can tell what kind of browser is accessing your site by getting the user agent string.

You can get it on the server side with PHP, Java, Python, etc... or you can get it on the client side with javascript.

In PHP it's stored in the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] superglobal. This PHP echoes the user agent string back to the user:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

In javascript it's in the navigator.userAgent variable. This javascript shows the users his user agent:

```
alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

The user agent string for the Facebook app will look something like this:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12F69 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/28.0.0.10.10;FBBV/8930087;FBDV/iPad4,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/8.3;FBSS/2; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/1]

Specifically, it's the FBAN/FBIOS part that identifies it as a Facebook app.

NOTE: The user agent string is pretty unreliable because it's so easy to fake. For your purpose it's not a big deal, but you shouldn't make actual programming decisions based on the user agent string.